# Empty response to json call (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to retrieve the json response that is called by loading this page: http://www.nzracing.co.nz/RaceInfo.aspx

Fiddler2 shows that this page gets json content from http://www.nzracing.co.nz/ServerScript/RaceInfo.aspx/GetCalendarEvents, passing a start and end date - e.g. {'start':'26-May-2013', 'end':'07-Jul-2013'}

I'm trying to retrieve this content, but all I get is an empty string. This is my function:

```
Public Function GetPage() As String

    Dim url As String = "http://www.nzracing.co.nz/ServerScript/RaceInfo.aspx/GetCalendarEvents"
    Dim json As String = "{'start':'26-May-2013', 'end':'07-Jul-2013'}"
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)

    request.ContentType = "text/json"
    request.Method = "POST"

    Dim streamWriter = New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
    streamWriter.Write(json)

    Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

    Return responseText
End Function
```

responseText is an empty string. In the past when I've retrieved web content (traditional get/post, no json previously) sometimes the referrer is required, so I tried adding

```
    request.Referer = "http://www.nzracing.co.nz/RaceInfo.aspx"
```

Still no difference. Then I noticed there was a cookie with some sort of sessionid. So I added the value I had when I loaded it in my browser:

```
    request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
    request.CookieContainer.Add(New Uri("http://www.nzracing.co.nz"), New Cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "1udhwsgqwqzv4innpp4noxao"))
```

Still nothing, so I programmatically retrieved the original page, got the CookieCollection and passed the entire CookieCollection to the request here. Still nothing.

I'm obviously missing something fairly fundamental here, but I can't work out what's wrong.

Looking further, (a page I can't reference because I'm a new user) suggests I have my url & json string wrong. So I changed these to

```
Dim url As String = "http://www.nzracing.co.nz/ServerScript/RaceInfo.aspx"
Dim json As String = "{'method':GetCalendarEvents', 'params':['start':'26-May-2013', 'end':'07-Jul-2013']}"
```

Hooray! I get a response. But it's just the html of the original page I first mentioned. Not the json response I see in Fiddler2. Still not right then.

Help? Why am I not getting the json response I'm expecting?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [WebClient.UploadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (and any [WebClient Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekfaaeay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))? They are usually easier than WebRequest and Stream.

It should be as simple as:

```
Dim WC as New Net.WebClient
Dim responseText as String = WC.UploadString(url, json)
```

Comment: Wow, yes - that is a lot simpler. But same result - an empty string.

Comment: Just add the content-type. It works for me. WC.Headers("Content-Type") = "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

You are using a POST as your request method. Usually, posts are used when you want to change something on the server. If you are just requesting information from a server, you use a GET.

What HTTP status code are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting a status 200 (OK).  

If I change from POST to GET, the request.GetRequestStream() throws an exception "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type"